# Prototype Ajax.Updater not working correctly with delay

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, delay

What I got here is a Ajax.Updater prototype js function. It's working perfectly this way:

```
new Ajax.Updater('feedback', 'contact.php', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: Form.serialize($('contactForm')),
    onFailure: reportError
});
```

But I want to delay the process a bit. I asked around on the prototype irc channel and this seems the way to go:

```
var feedback = function() {
    new Ajax.Updater('feedback', 'contact.php', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: Form.serialize($('contactForm')),
        onFailure: reportError
    });

    new Effect.Highlight('feedback', {
        duration: 1
    });
}
feedback.delay(1.5);
```

(don t mind the scriptaculous effect)

There is a echo function in contact.php that looks like this:

```
echo("Thanks for your message $_POST['Name']!");
```

After applying the delay the name is no longer echoed! What's wrong?

Comment: Does javascript report any errors? Which ones? Try firefox's tools -> error console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok last try on this one. This works for me and does what you want

My html-file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asd</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/prototype.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/scriptaculous.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var feedback = function() {
                var params = Form.serialize($('contactForm'));
                new Ajax.Updater('feedback', 'contact.php', {
                    method: 'post',
                    parameters: params,
                    onFailure: reportError,
                    asynchronous:true
                });

                new Effect.Highlight('feedback', {
                    duration: 1
                });
            }
            function reportError(request) { alert("error");} 

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="contactForm">
            <p>Name:<br><input name="Name" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>
            <input name="sendbutton" type="button" value="Send" onClick="feedback.delay(1.5);">
        </form>
        <div id="feedback">foo</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My *contact.php*

```
<?php
echo("Thanks for your message ".$_POST['Name']."!");
?>
```

and using the js files from [here](http://script.aculo.us/dist/scriptaculous-js-1.8.2.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just wrap the thing in a [setTimeOut](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_settimeout.asp) call. Thus delaying the ajax request instead of delaying the displaying. Which is btw excatly what the prototype delay function does

But

```
new Ajax.Updater.delay(2, 'feedback', 'contact.php', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: Form.serialize($('contactForm')),
    onFailure: reportError
});
```

should also work

Comment: I tried to wrap the thing into a setTimeout call without succes.
The point is: the Ajax.Updater is within a chain and the displaying itself has to be delayed.

Prototype's delay function as an argument would be the nicest option and I also tried it at first but Firebug gives me this error:
__method.apply is not a function
[Break on this error] return __method.apply(__method, args);

Answer (score 0):

I give it another try.

Change

```
echo("Thanks for your message $_POST['Name']!");
```

to

```
echo("Thanks for your message ".$_POST['Name']."!");
```

and try again.

And make sure you have implemented the `reportError` function you pass in here

```
onFailure: reportError
```

e.g.

```
function reportError(request){alert('Shit happens!');}
```

Comment: Did you also try the different echo variant I suggested?

Comment: I tried the echo variant but there is no difference. reportError is not called. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't apply to the original question asked - but since I came across this thread in my search. Figured I'd post my results.

I had some code an ajax updater suddenly stop working:

```
new Ajax.Updater('my_id, 'http://mydomain.com/my_script.php');
```

The reason it didnt work for me because I was on www.mydomain.com (opposed to mydomain.com)

I simply changed it to:

```
new Ajax.Updater('my_id, 'my_script.php');
```

and it worked fine.